# How to call a javascript on dropdown

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap

I have the a dropdown list. On selecting an option I want to display a calendar. The drop down switches work fine, but the calendar gets loaded when the website loads first time. Later the dropdown list functions as required. Please tell where I am doing the mistake.

```
 <form class="form-horizontal form-label-left top_margin">
                        <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="control-label col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12">Select The Class/Batch</label>
                    <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                      <select class="form-control" id="division" onchange="calendar">
                        <option>Select One</option>
                        <option value="1">Standard 1 Divison A</option>
                        <option value="2">Standard 1 Divison B</option>
                        <option value="3">Standard 1 Divison C</option>
                        <option value="4">Standard 1 Divison D</option>
                      </select>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <br>
                  <br>
                  <br>
                    </form>
                    <div id="caldisplay">
                         <div id='calendar'></div>
                    </div>
```

My javascripts:

```
 <script>
    $('#division').on('change',function(){
 var selection = $(this).val();
switch(selection){
case "1":
$("#caldisplay").show()
break;
default:
$("#caldisplay").hide()
}
});
</script>






   $(function() { // document ready

    $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
        now: '2016-05-07',
        editable: true,
        aspectRatio: 1.8,
        scrollTime: '00:00',
        header: {
            left: 'prev,next',
            center: 'title',
            right: 'timelineMonth,timelineYear'
        },
        defaultView: 'timelineMonth',
        resourceAreaWidth: '25%',
        resourceLabelText: 'Students',
        resources: [
            { id: 'a', title: 'John Doe A' },
            { id: 'b', title: 'John Doe B' },
            { id: 'c', title: 'John Doe C' },
            { id: 'e', title: 'John Doe E' },
            { id: 'f', title: 'John Doe F' },
            { id: 'g', title: 'John Doe G' },
            { id: 'h', title: 'John Doe H' },
            { id: 'i', title: 'John Doe I' },
            { id: 'j', title: 'John Doe J' },
            { id: 'k', title: 'John Doe K' },
            { id: 'l', title: 'John Doe L' },
            { id: 'm', title: 'John Doe M' },
            { id: 'n', title: 'John Doe N' },
            { id: 'o', title: 'John Doe O' },
            { id: 'p', title: 'John Doe P' },
            { id: 'q', title: 'John Doe Q' },
            { id: 'r', title: 'John Doe R' },
            { id: 's', title: 'John Doe S' },
            { id: 't', title: 'John Doe T' },
            { id: 'u', title: 'John Doe U' },
            { id: 'v', title: 'John Doe V' },
            { id: 'w', title: 'John Doe W' },
            { id: 'x', title: 'John Doe X' },
            { id: 'y', title: 'John Doe Y' },
            { id: 'z', title: 'John Doe Z' }
        ],
        events: [
            { id: '1', resourceId: 'b', start: '2016-05-07', end: '2016-05-07', title: 'X' },
            { id: '1', resourceId: 'b', start: '2016-05-06', end: '2016-05-06', title: 'X' },
            { id: '2', resourceId: 'c', start: '2016-05-07', end: '2016-05-07', title: 'O' },
            { id: '3', resourceId: 'd', start: '2016-05-06', end: '2016-05-06', title: 'O' },
            { id: '4', resourceId: 'e', start: '2016-05-07', end: '2016-05-07', title: 'X' },
            { id: '5', resourceId: 'f', start: '2016-05-07', end: '2016-05-07', title: 'X' }
        ]
    });

});

 </script>
```

Comment: Check if the first script closing tag is really needed. If it does, consider introduce other starting script tag after that.

Comment: is this suppose to be in there 'onchange="calendar"'?  if not Remove it as it may be causing an error

Comment: Try hiding the calendar after instantiating: $('#calendar').fullCalendar({ ... }).hide()

Comment: You really don't need a `switch` statement when you only handle two different situations, just use an `if`-`else`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to use switch for just one simple function, by default u can hide it with **CSS** or if u want to show it when selection is different, u can use **IF/ELSE** statement..

Everything what u need to do is call the function like this:

**On change call:**

```
<select class="form-control" id="division" onchange="calendar()">
```

**Function in JS:**

```
    function calendar() {
        $calendar = $('#calendar');
        $calendar.show();

        $calendar.fullCalendar({
            now: '2016-05-07',
            editable: true,
            aspectRatio: 1.8,
            scrollTime: '00:00',
            header: {
                left: 'prev,next',
                center: 'title',
                right: 'timelineMonth,timelineYear'
            },
            defaultView: 'timelineMonth',
            resourceAreaWidth: '25%',
            resourceLabelText: 'Students',
            resources: [
                { id: 'a', title: 'John Doe A' },
                { id: 'b', title: 'John Doe B' },
                { id: 'c', title: 'John Doe C' },
                { id: 'e', title: 'John Doe E' },
                { id: 'f', title: 'John Doe F' },
                { id: 'g', title: 'John Doe G' },
                { id: 'h', title: 'John Doe H' },
                { id: 'i', title: 'John Doe I' },
                { id: 'j', title: 'John Doe J' },
                { id: 'k', title: 'John Doe K' },
                { id: 'l', title: 'John Doe L' },
                { id: 'm', title: 'John Doe M' },
                { id: 'n', title: 'John Doe N' },
                { id: 'o', title: 'John Doe O' },
                { id: 'p', title: 'John Doe P' },
                { id: 'q', title: 'John Doe Q' },
                { id: 'r', title: 'John Doe R' },
                { id: 's', title: 'John Doe S' },
                { id: 't', title: 'John Doe T' },
                { id: 'u', title: 'John Doe U' },
                { id: 'v', title: 'John Doe V' },
                { id: 'w', title: 'John Doe W' },
                { id: 'x', title: 'John Doe X' },
                { id: 'y', title: 'John Doe Y' },
                { id: 'z', title: 'John Doe Z' }
            ],
            events: [
                { id: '1', resourceId: 'b', start: '2016-05-07', end: '2016-05-07', title: 'X' },
                { id: '1', resourceId: 'b', start: '2016-05-06', end: '2016-05-06', title: 'X' },
                { id: '2', resourceId: 'c', start: '2016-05-07', end: '2016-05-07', title: 'O' },
                { id: '3', resourceId: 'd', start: '2016-05-06', end: '2016-05-06', title: 'O' },
                { id: '4', resourceId: 'e', start: '2016-05-07', end: '2016-05-07', title: 'X' },
                { id: '5', resourceId: 'f', start: '2016-05-07', end: '2016-05-07', title: 'X' }
            ]
        });
   }
```

Comment: It worked. Thanks a lot. How to load the same function on tab. When we click on the tab to display the same function?

Comment: I mean the normal tab panel.

Comment: In the previous example, I need the javascript to work when I click one drop down. Not all.

Comment: So when u select something, do i understand right, sorry i've been busy